# How to pass value from view to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In controller i have function `public ActionResult Index(int id,int test= 0,int to=10){}` I try to change value test from view on click to get test+=10 but i dont know how. I tryed with action link and ajax but its not working. Any ideas?
My view code :

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Countries</title>
    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Matches</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            @foreach (var i in Model.ListMatch)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(i.Description, "", new { id = i.Id })</td>

                </tr>




            }

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I return results to ng-view. Can i do something like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Countries",new { id = i.Id, from+=10 })"></a>
```

Comment: Please show your view code.

Comment: there is my view code

Comment: Do you want to add 10 to test variable in each call to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't explained very well, but from what I gather you want to be able to make a change to a value without reloading the page or leaving that view.

In order to do this you have to use AJAX. I know you said you tried AJAX but perhaps you got something wrong. Try this:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function() {
   $.post( "/YourController/YourFunction", function() {
      alert( "success" );
   });
});
```